# Matlab 'For' loop and line plotting [Beginners question]

Tags: matlab

```
function  question2a(a,x)
  y=zeros(1000,1);
  y(1)=x;
  hold on;
  for j=2:1000
     y(j) = a*y(j-1)*exp(-y(j-1));
     plot(j, y);
  end
  hold off;
end
```

Is my code for a certain exercise, however I am not getting a line instead of a line I am getting a lot of dots. Can someone please explain me how I can fix this?

The function should replicate this:

$$y_{n+1}=\alpha \cdot y_{n} \cdot e^{-y_n}$$

$$y_1 = \alpha \cdot y_0 \cdot e^{-y_0}, \qquad y_2 = \alpha \cdot y_1 \cdot e^{-y_1} =  \alpha \cdot \alpha \cdot y_0 \cdot e^{-y_0} \cdot e^{-\alpha \cdot  y_0 \cdot e^{-y_0}}, \qquad \ldots$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Advice** Have a look [the Matlab documentation center](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html)

**Hint** Run this code in a script and try to understand what is your problem.

```
z = rand(8,1);

figure
for i = 1:8
    plot(i,z(i));
    hold on;
end;
hold off;

figure
plot((1:8),z);

figure
plot(z);
```

Comment: I got it, so stupid..if it is in the loop it will calculate and plot the graph for every point if it is outside the loop it will draw a line, thanks again!